# what is the difference between WidgetsApp class, MaterialApp class and Directionality class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Can anyone please tell me what are the differences between WidgetsApp class, MaterialApp class and Directionality class?. Can I say WidgetsApp is inherited from Directionality? because both of them I can use them for layout non material apps.

Answer (score 8):

**MaterialApp** builds upon a **WidgetsApp** by **adding material-design** specific functionality.

As stated in the official Flutter documentation:

### [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html):

> A convenience widget that wraps a number of widgets that are commonly
>   required for material design applications.
>
> It builds upon a WidgetsApp
>   by adding material-design specific functionality, such as
>   AnimatedTheme and GridPaper.

### [WidgetsApp:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp-class.html)

> A convenience class that wraps a number of widgets that are commonly
>   required for an application.
>
> One of the primary roles that WidgetsApp provides is binding the
>   system back button to popping the Navigator or quitting the
>   application.

Answer (score 2):

WidgetsApp class is actually the base class for MaterialApp class and the CupertionApp class. Whereas Directionality is actually a class which provides the default direction for the text in sub-tree in the app. MaterialApp contains WidgetsApp class and Directionality class (so there is always a default direction for Text widget ), and custom transitions, and many other modifications/additions as per material specification in your app (Which is probably the error which brought you to asking this question). Hope this helps.